# disable formatting when using cut and paste

Tags: clipboard, openbox

I am using `openbox` as my window manager. When I copy and paste using <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> from one application into another, it transfers the text formatting together with the text.

I have to use plaintext editor in between, so that the formatting is lost.

This is pure evil. I assume this was invented by the same people who gave us <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, just to drive people crazy and waste millions of man-hours yearly.

Anyway, how can I disable this in openbox?

I am aware of this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219688/remove-formatting-from-copy-paste-buffer), but I am not sure how to integrate the suggested solution in my situation.

I don't use any external clipboard program, I don't have `xclip` or `xsel` installed. I assume the copy/paste functionality is native to `openbox`?

## UPDATE:

as I explained in the comments, this happens for example when copying from `chromium` and pasting into `firefox`. Using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+v</kbd> does seem to work, and pastes text without formatting. However, it is another extra step i need to remember. I have <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> ingrained in my muscle memory. is it possible to re-define the key shortcut, so that <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> acts as if i used <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+v</kbd> ?

Comment: Does ctrl+shift+v for pasting work?

Comment: @terdon - no, ctrl+shift+v does nothing

Comment: Copying and pasting doesn’t depend on the window manager, it depends on the program you’re copying from and the program you’re pasting to. Could you clarify which programs you’re having trouble with?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - for example copy text from chromium, and paste to firefox.

Comment: Paste where in firefox? Onto a field in a webpage? Surely you are not seeing formatted text when pasting into the address or search boxes, right? In any case, I agree that it is annoying, but for me, ctrl+shift+v pastes it with no formatting in most programs. As does select and middle click paste. Does neither of those work for you?

Comment: @terdon - pasting into firefox text field, for example when writing post on reddit. I tried in firefox, and ctrl+shift+v seems to work there. But that's again one more step to remember when pasting. Is it possible to make ctrl+v always work as ctrl+shift+v ?

Comment: I personally almost never use ctrl+c/v as I find them cumbersome and always default to selecting text and then middle clicking to paste like a good, old school *nix geek. Does that not work for you? Since nobody has answered, it might make sense to edit this and change it to ask how to make the ctrl+v behave like ctrl+shift+v but since it is apparently handled by individual programs, I don't know if anyone will be able to help.

Comment: You probably do have some sort of clipboard program. Could be xclip, glipper, gpaste, clipit, or something else — Openbox  [doesn't seem to have that built in](https://github.com/danakj/openbox/search?q=clipboard+OR+paste&type=code). You could find out by just trying to run some of those commands. You could use [keybinds](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) to remap with a `<command>` action

Comment: Related: [Save HTML from clipboard as markdown text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78395)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer: Selections in X don't work like in Windows. The X protocol allows two clients to communicate and transfer the selection, and these two clients also negotiate the format between them. There is no "system-wide clipboard".

So it's not something that is "built into openbox".

(In addition, usage of <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd> is also application dependent, not all applications offer those keys. The X standard is to use the middle mouse button for paste.)

So the only way to get rid of this functionality is to introduce a third client (similar to `xclipboard`, note that this is very different from `xclip`) which implements some kind of system-wide clipboard, takes over the selection and only copies the text format.

However, I do not know of any ready-made application that has this functionality.

Depending on your level of pain, and your C expertise, you could look at the source code of `xclipboard` and modify it so it only copies the text format.

Comment: You could always do it with something like `while true; do xclip -sel c -o | xclip -sel c -quiet; done`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That might actually work, and you could also throw in `-t` to pick a specific format.

Comment: Used in [Save HTML from clipboard as markdown text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78395) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Openbox does not offer this functionality. I have to agree with @dirkt that this can be only done by third party client.

I know you won't probably like it as you are using lightweight openbox, but a clipboard manager that offers this functionality is [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) (yes, you have to have installed QT libraries that CopyQ needs).

In order to paste as plain text in CopyQ you need to add a command.  This is from the FAQ where I originally found it (and used it):

### How to paste as plain text?

To paste clipboard as plain text:

- Open “Command” dialog (F6 shortcut).
- Click “Add” button in the dialog.
- Select “Paste clipboard as plain text” from the list and click “OK”
  button.
- Click the button next to “Global Shortcut” label and set the
  shortcut.
- Click “OK” button to save the changes.

**To paste selected items as plain text** (from CopyQ window) follow the steps above but add *Paste as Plain Text* command instead and change *Shortcut*.

Here are the [CopyQ's FAQ](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html).